# k-means with a centroid constraint

Tags: python, algorithm, k-means, data-science

I'm working on a data science project for my intro to Data Science class, and we've decided to tackle a problem relating to desalination plants in california: "Where should we place k plants to minimize the distance to zip codes?"

The data that we have so far is, zip, city, county, pop, lat, long, amount of water.

The issue is, I can't find any resources on how to force the centroid to be constrained to staying on the coast. What we've thought of so far is:
Use a normal kmeans algorithm, but move the centroid to the coast once clusters have settled (bad)
Use a normal kmeans algorithm with weights, making the coastal zips have infinite weight (I've been told this isn't a great solution)

What do you guys think?

Comment: IANA data scientist, but could you discretize the coastal line, then choose the ones with the least within-cluster sum of squares? Redefining the update step would be harder though. I'm going to dwell on this for a while now.

Comment: I don't think my initial idea will scale well.  Instead, you could redefine the update step to project the new mean back onto the coast.  That should be straight forward.  First compute the new mean, then find the closest point on the coast to that new mean.  The algorithm will keep trying to pull the means off the coast, and you have to keep pushing them back.  I expect that eventually, the delta will be perpendicular to the coast, but that's just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by setting possible points that could be centers, i.e. your coastline.
I think this is close to [Nathaniel Saul's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8054875/nathaniel-saul) first comment.
This way, for each iteration, instead of choosing a mean, a point out of the possible set would be chosen by proximity to the cluster.

I’ve simplified the conditions to only 2 data columns (lon. and lat.) but you should be able to extrapolate the concept. For simplicity, to demonstrate, I based this on code from [here](https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/clustering-with-k-means-in-python/).

### In this example, the purple dots are places on the coastline. If I understood correctly, the optimal Coastline locations should look something like this:

[image: Coastline Optimum]

### See code below:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.6

# Code based on:
# https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/clustering-with-k-means-in-python/

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

##### Simulation START #####
# Generate possible points.
def possible_points(n=20):
    y=list(np.linspace( -1, 1, n ))
    x=[-1.2]
    X=[]
    for i in list(range(1,n)):
        x.append(x[i-1]+random.uniform(-2/n,2/n) )
    for a,b in zip(x,y):
        X.append(np.array([a,b]))
    X = np.array(X)
    return X

# Generate sample
def init_board_gauss(N, k):
    n = float(N)/k
    X = []
    for i in range(k):
        c = (random.uniform(-1, 1), random.uniform(-1, 1))
        s = random.uniform(0.05,0.5)
        x = []
        while len(x) < n:
            a, b = np.array([np.random.normal(c[0], s), np.random.normal(c[1], s)])
            # Continue drawing points from the distribution in the range [-1,1]
            if abs(a) < 1 and abs(b) < 1:
                x.append([a,b])
        X.extend(x)
    X = np.array(X)[:N]
    return X
##### Simulation END #####    

# Identify points for each center.
def cluster_points(X, mu):
    clusters  = {}
    for x in X:
        bestmukey = min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-mu[i[0]])) \
                    for i in enumerate(mu)], key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
        try:
            clusters[bestmukey].append(x)
        except KeyError:
            clusters[bestmukey] = [x]
    return clusters

# Get closest possible point for each cluster.
def closest_point(cluster,possiblePoints):
    closestPoints=[]
    # Check average distance for each point.
    for possible in possiblePoints:
        distances=[]
        for point in cluster:
            distances.append(np.linalg.norm(possible-point))
            closestPoints.append(np.sum(distances)) # minimize total distance
            # closestPoints.append(np.mean(distances))
    return possiblePoints[closestPoints.index(min(closestPoints))]

# Calculate new centers.
# Here the 'coast constraint' goes.
def reevaluate_centers(clusters,possiblePoints):
    newmu = []
    keys = sorted(clusters.keys())
    for k in keys:
        newmu.append(closest_point(clusters[k],possiblePoints))
    return newmu

# Check whether centers converged.
def has_converged(mu, oldmu):
    return (set([tuple(a) for a in mu]) == set([tuple(a) for a in oldmu]))

# Meta function that runs the steps of the process in sequence.
def find_centers(X, K, possiblePoints):
    # Initialize to K random centers
    oldmu = random.sample(list(possiblePoints), K)
    mu = random.sample(list(possiblePoints), K)
    while not has_converged(mu, oldmu):
        oldmu = mu
        # Assign all points in X to clusters
        clusters = cluster_points(X, mu)
        # Re-evaluate centers
        mu = reevaluate_centers(clusters,possiblePoints)
    return(mu, clusters)


K=3
X = init_board_gauss(30,K)
possiblePoints=possible_points()
results=find_centers(X,K,possiblePoints)

# Show results

# Show constraints and clusters
# List point types
pointtypes1=["gx","gD","g*"]

plt.plot(
    np.matrix(possiblePoints).transpose()[0],np.matrix(possiblePoints).transpose()[1],'m.'
    )

for i in list(range(0,len(results[0]))) :
    plt.plot(
        np.matrix(results[0][i]).transpose()[0], np.matrix(results[0][i]).transpose()[1],pointtypes1[i]
        )

pointtypes=["bx","yD","c*"]
# Show all cluster points
for i in list(range(0,len(results[1]))) :
    plt.plot(
        np.matrix(results[1][i]).transpose()[0],np.matrix(results[1][i]).transpose()[1],pointtypes[i]
        )
plt.show()
```

Edited to minimize total distance.

Answer (score 1):

K-means does not minimize distances.

It minimizes **squared errors**, which is *quite* different.
The difference is roughly that of the median, and the mean in 1 dimensional data. The error can be massive.

Here is a counter example, assuming we have the coordinates:

```
-1 0
+1 0
 0 -1
 0 101
```

The center chosen by k-means would be 0,25. The optimal location is 0,0.
The sum of distances by k-means is > 152, the optimum location has distance 104. So here, the centroid is almost 50% worse than the optimum! But the centroid (= multivariate mean) is what k-means uses!

### k-means does not minimize the Euclidean distance!

This is one variant how "k-means is sensitive to outliers".

It does not get better if you try to constrain it to place "centers" on the coast only...

Also, you may want to at least use Haversine distance, because in California, 1 degree north != 1 degree east, because it's not at the Equator.

Furthermore, you likely should *not* make the assumption that every location requires its own pipe, but rather they will be connected like a tree. This greatly reduces the cost.

I strongly suggest to treat this as a generic optimization problem, rather than k-means. K-means is an optimization too, but it may optimize the wrong function for your problem...